# .htaccess and PHP caching

Tags: php, .htaccess

This one is a relatively simple one hopefully. We just launched a site and uploaded it to a new server. In uploading the .htaccess file, we made a small mistake and when we went to correct it, it didn't seem to update.

We deleted the .htaccess file altogether and yet for some reason it seems to have cached itself on the server... I think. We have hard refreshed, tried different machines, different browsers and it still pulls in the dynamic pages.

I have never experienced this before.

Does anyone know how to force / hard refresh a htaccess file>?

Comment: "Does anyone know how to force / hard refresh a htaccess file>?" - there is no such thing. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Look through your directories for other .htaccess files deeper in.  The file is read and parsed on each request, never cached so once it's gone it is no longer active. (Browsers sometimes like to hold onto bad redirects though)

Comment: does your httpd.conf on the new server allow .htaccess? ps you cont need and cant refresh a .htaccess file...its like you stated, a file...nothning more

Comment: You need to check if redirect module is enabled in apache2.

Comment: `it still pulls in the dynamic pages` please clarify what it is that you've added, deleted, expected behavior and what's actually happening. Without something specific the question is simply vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not understanding what you describe as happenning since you deleted the file, and you've not said what was in the .htaccess which which caused the problem, nor what the resulting impact was.

However....you don't need to do anything more than delete the .htaccess file - Apache does not cache it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a little odd for me – I am not the biggest noob in the world when it comes to creating sites though obviously I have done something odd / wrong here.

I removed all instances of the folder/files the .htaccess referenced to and indeed the .htaccess file to force a 404. I then re-uploaded the php file and the htaccess and it seems to be behaving now.

What an odd thing. Thanks again for all your thoughts.